# Javascript .replace works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, replace

The following attempt to replace whitespaces with hyphens works in Firefox but not IE:

```
metatext = metatext.replace(/[\s]/g,"-");
```

Neither do the following alternative attempts work in IE:

```
metatext = metatext.replace(/[\s+]/g,"-");

metatext = metatext.replace(/[ ]/g,"-");
```

Insights appreciated.

Comment: Sample input and desired output? "Works" is about as useless as it gets. Also "IE" encompasses ten products spanning almost two decades; be more specific.

Comment: working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/BnSEG/

Comment: Is the variable `metatext` a string? Ad@m

Comment: [Works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/zCeaL/) for me in IE8.

Comment: @Tomalak and @Nilas jsfiddle examples work in IE9...

Comment: @Keoki: Thanks for testing that.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably considered a messy solution, but you could probably try whichever of these you need.

http://phpjs.org/functions/str_ireplace:524 
http://phpjs.org/functions/substr_replace:819

str_ireplace is the case-insensitive version of str_replace in PHP.

You may also want to try `metatext = metatext.replace(/\s/g, "-");`

Comment: Thanks for responses.  Took metatext = metatext.replace(/[\xa0]/g,"-"); to resolve it.

Comment: For the record, you don't need the [ and ] chars in your regex.